# Probability, Linear Models, Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, regression

> I'm trying to find a way of predicting various models from one "perfect model", using
>   EXCEL. 
>   i.e. If I assume that all models should behave like the original one, for which I
>   have all the data, I would like to find out the missing data based on the "perfect 
>   model".
>   So the problem is as follows: I'm selling the same TV model to 10 different clients and over the 
>   span of 1 year I record how many complaints each client made. So the data looks
>   like this: 
>   Client ID-#of Complaints 
>   Client1- 3
>   Client2- 17
>   Client3- 0
>   Client4-  7
>   Client5- 6
>   Client6- 20
>   Client7- 1
>   Client8-  7
>   Client9-2
>   Client10- 5
>   Now If a have the data of 10 other clients for half a year, can I predict what the # of complaints will be by the end of the year?
>   Client ID-#of Complaints 
>   Client1-13
>   Client2-  7
>   Client3-10
>   Client4-  3
>   Client5- 4
>   Client6- 2 
>   Client7- 9
>   Client8-  7
>   Client9-1
>   Client10- 2
>   Any advice on how I should go about this using excel would be greatly appreciated 
>   Thanks

Comment: You might be more successful posting this question on CrossValidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you assuming that the complaint rate does not vary over the course of the year?

Comment: Yes, it does not vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using complaint data from one set of customers, in a previous year, to predict the complaints from another set of customers in a different year, you are implicity making the following assumptions:

1. The complaints from each customer are iid.
2. Each customer has the same complaint distribution this year as last year.

Under these assumptions, you can do the following:

1. Resample with replacement from your "perfect model" to create a new random sample of size 10. You can do this in excel using VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),$A$2:$B$11,2), where the lookup table has column 1 as the client number, column 2 as the total complaints. you will enter this formula in 10 columns, one per client in the sample.

   2. Copy this formula for 1000 rows to generate 1000 iid samples of 10 client compliants from your "perfect model".
   3. Sum up the total number of complaints in each sample
   4. Copy the sum column and *paste values* into a separate column. This will be an estimate of your total complaint distribution for 10 clients.
   5. Your half year data shows 58 compliants. What you want is the *conditional* distribution of total annual compliants, *given* that the total will be at least 58. I.e., you want to estimate $P(C\leq c|C>57)$. You can do this by forming a cumulative distribution function from your resampled totals, truncating it at 58 and then re-scaling the CDF by subtracting the percentile value of 57 and dividing by 1 minus the percentile of 57. Now you will have a conditional CDF of possible annual compliants given you have at least 58. You can form prediction intervals from this by taking off various quantiles that encompass your desired level of coverage.

I've attached some screen shots of my analysis of your data to show you what can be done:

The first shows three "resample" distributions I got from your data. Note that using 1000 resamples results in very little variability in the estimated distributions. The second shows the conditional distribution, based on your half year sample. The third shows the spreadsheet I used so you can see it did not require anything but plain vanilla Excel. It took about 10 minutes to put together.

[image: Resamples]
[image: conditional dist]
[image: excel]

Comment: That's really nice! Would you be able to email (israeln1@hotmail.com) me that excel file.

Comment: @Dave I've sent you a copy. It's a pretty simple spreadsheet. Hope it helps. Please accept the answer if you feel it was what you are looking for.